# How can I create a directory in BlackBerry internal memory

Tags: java, blackberry, file-io

I am trying to create a directory to store my application's files in the BlackBerry's internal memory. Here's the code:

```
String uri = "file:///store/testapp/";
FileConnection dir;
try {
    dir = (FileConnection)Connector.open(uri, Connector.READ_WRITE);
    if (!dir.exists()){             
        dir.mkdir();    
    }
    dir.close();    

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

When I run the above I get an `IOException` with the message "File System Error (12)". Looking this up in the list of [BlackBerry constant values](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/file/FileIOException.html#INVALID_OPERATION) this corresponds to "The operation requested is invalid.". Why can't I create the `testapp` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own directories only in: "file:///store/home/user/"

Comment: Doh! Just figured that out myself: file:///store/ and file:///store/home/ are not writeable. Shame "The operation requested is invalid" error message is so cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

You should only create directories in "**file:///store/home/user/**" or "**file:///store/home/samples/**" only;

For creating a directory:

```
public void createDirectory()
{
    FileConnection file=null;
    try 
    {
        String Path="file:///store/home/user/Abc/"; // or path="file:///store/home/samples/Abc/"
        file = (FileConnection)Connector.open(Path);
        if(!file.exists())
            file.mkdir();
        file.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        try 
        {
            if(file!=null)
            {
                file.close();
            }
            System.out.println("==============Exception: "+e.getMessage());
        } 
        catch (IOException e1) 
        {
            
        } 
    }     
}
```

There is different in "**file:///store/home/user/Abc/**" and "**file:///store/home/user/Abc**"

> If you put like "file:///store/home/user/**Abc**" then it take the "Abc" as file;
>
> If you put like "file:///store/home/user/**Abc/**" then it take the "Abc" as directory;